# ReSharper is trying to rename "private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;"

Tags: c#, resharper

I don't have a problem with ReSharper but some where in my study I read that using "_" is not recomended.

ReSharper is trying to rename From

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

To

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button _button1;
```

EDIT: Note that I don't want to change it, I am asking if the _xxx is the standard. Why is visual studio not putting it?

Comment: Anyway this is the best software I brought for visual studio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use "_". In any case, the naming rules can be changed in ReSharper->Options.

Comment: I create these GUI before I installed ReSharper so I think it's trying to rename it to the standard?

Comment: It's renaming to your current settings. If you haven't changed those settings, then it's renaming to the defaults. There is no single "standard".

Comment: Under options, you can change the Naming Style - depending on the version of R# you have, you might need to change it under: Languages: Common, or Languages: C#. @Jonathan Shepherd - it's trying to rename it to *a* standard, but you are allowed to define a different one if that suits you better - our instance fields are defined as m_UpperCamelCase to visually differentiate them from constants or public fields, while local variables are lowerCamelCase - For want of a better guide, we've pretty much adopted the IDesign C# Coding Standard: http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid Thanks for your reply. I am reading right now.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper -> Options -> Languages -> Common -> Naming Style

change

Instance fields(private) to lowerCamelCase
Static fields(private) to lowerCamelCase